# How to get rid of multiple usages of bn.js in nextjs bundle?

Tags: reactjs, bundle, analyzer

Is there a way to unify dependencies in `react/nextjs` to avoid multiple usages of a specific library ( in this case `bn.js` ) in the final bundle?

My application suffers from bundle size and when I use `nextjs analyzer` I see a lot of usages of this library and I was wondering if there is something to apply and use this once!?

[image]

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69141829/how-to-avoid-duplication-of-module-bn-js-in-webpack-production-build

Comment: @rvanlaarhoven please take a look at creation time of both questions.

Comment: You're right. Didn't see that. Just wanted to link both issues as the same question