# How to avoid duplication of module "bn.js" in webpack production build?

Tags: node.js, webpack, node-modules

I used webpack 4 for my app. Somehow, `bn.js` package takes up a lot in production build.

[image: Image 1]

The image shows that it takes up `594.22` KB of data. Is there any way to have a 1 file of `bn.js`  for all packages that depends on `bn.js`?

Answer (score 2):

This likely happens because your dependencies all require different versions of `bn.js`. You could try to define one specific version in the resolutions list in your `package.json`:

```
{
  // ...
  "resolutions": {
    "bn.js": "^5.1.1"
  }
}
```

Keep in mind that newer versions might contain breaking changes which some of the dependencies depended on. You could evaluate your `package-lock.json` or `yarn.lock` to see what versions of `bn.js` are required throughout the dependencies and compare that with the changelog